# "Text must be rendered within <Text>" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am creating an application in React Native (Expo) using Snack. This program was working an hour ago, but now it shows this error.

> `Device: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.`

### [Snack Link](https://snack.expo.io/@dipamsen/d68d6c)

I know why this error occurs, but  I don't know where exactly the error is.

Things Tried:
Checked for

- potential text out of `<Text>` component
- extra spaces left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ButtonGroup.js

```
 <Button
      onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Project_Submit');
      }}
      icon="publish"
      type="entypo"
      name="Submit Project"
    />{' '}

Replace with


<Button
      onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Project_Submit');
      }}
      icon="publish"
      type="entypo"
      name="Submit Project"
    />
```

Line 31 is a text

Comment: Oh... the autoformat is terrible... BTW thanks a lot! also, this question is actually useless, so should I delete it?